# Convert Image to Bytes and save in Xml

Tags: c#, image, process, stream

I need to convert byte [] of an image to a format that can be saved in a xml.
I tried to convert to a string but not worked.
The xml file after 5 images saved was about the size of 50mb!
I need to convert to a simpler format for this xml file can not be too heavy.

Comment: [Storing an Image in an XML File](http://developingfor.net/2008/10/01/storing-an-image-in-an-xml-file/) take a look here

Comment: If file size is important, xml may not be the most appropriate file format choice... it sounds like you should be using a binary format directly.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) format - you lose some efficiency but the data will be encapsulated. For example

```
<image name="MyPhoto.jpg">WFuIGlzIGRpc3Rpbmd1aXNoZWQsIG5vdCBvbm</image>
```

You can convert to Base64 using [`Convert.ToBase64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: then face so the file is still heavy, after converting the byte [] to string gets too big!

Answer (score 0):

Try compressing the byte array and hope the size will be smaller :). For example check :[DeflateStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.deflatestream.write%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and hope the size will be reduced :)